# What position order to put Host: directive in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

Should the Host directive in my robots.txt be at the top or the bottom of the file or does the order not matter.

Here is my robots.txt file :

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 10
Disallow: /administrator/
```

Does each User-Agent specified also require the host directive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Yandex: https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.html#host

> […] the `Host` directive is intersectional, so it will be used by the robot regardless of its location in `robots.txt`.
>
> For every `robots.txt` file, only one `Host` directive is processed. If several directives are indicated in the file, the robot will use the first one.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> Host: myhost.ru # uses
>
> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /cgi-bin
>
> User-agent: Yandex
> Disallow: /cgi-bin
> Host: www.myhost.ru # is not used
> ```

So regardless of what `User-Agent` the `Host` directive is under or how many `Host` directives there are in the robots.txt and position of them only the first occurrence will be the one that is used.